# no module named setuptools_rust

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, python-social-auth

hellow i'm new to python and django. Currently i'm trying to run a project made in django 1.10.2 and python 2.7 in ubuntu 16.04. The project uses a module called python-social-auth, which causes me the following error when I try to install.

[image]

Hopefully you can help me in detail to solve this problem because as I told you I am new to using these tools.

Comment: Please do not post code (exception, message, ...) as an image. For more information: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2437450

Comment: the project is very long for this

Comment: I don't know what options are available to compile `cryptography` and the quite-recent Rust dependency in Ubuntu 16.04, I'd suggest pinning the version for to the one previous to this change.

Comment: Try pip3 install setuptools_rust